# Comic Reader that supports animated .GIF images?

Tags: software-recommendation

Short and simple question -- is there a comic viewer that will allow me to view my .cb7 comic files with animation?

There are some comics and manga I have that have animated .GIF images that move -- in windows I was able to open and display these using honeyview.

Is there any similar program for Linux? Right now I have decompress the archives in order to view the animations...

Answer (score 1):

After some looking, I have determined there are currently NO applications for Linux that will open a .cb7 (7-zip compressed) archive and play the GIF images. My solution has been to extract these images into a folder and view them normally for now.

Answer (score 0):

[MComix](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/mcomix/) is available from the Software Centre.
It supports cbz, cbr, **cb7** and cbt archives and images in png, jpg, bmp, **gif** and many other formats.

Comment: Was not able to install from terminal or Software Centre as it is not available for 12.04 (only 12.10 and up). I did download and install version 1.00 though and while it does support and display gif just as comix has, it still does not support animation.

Comment: I see. I just found this old feature request: http://sourceforge.net/p/mcomix/feature-requests/11/ so it seems unles someone provides a working patch, this feature will never be included.

Answer (score -1):

[Linuxaria](http://linuxaria.com/recensioni/comic-book-viewers-for-linux) described five comic book readers that can process the archives.

Among them is **Calibre**, which I use frequently to process ebooks. But I'm not into comics, so I can't tell if animated GIFs are supported. They don't give any information in the survey either.

**EDIT**
Luis de Sousa's comment made me curious enough to run a single try. I can confirm that Calibre can import and display *.cbr archives. The one I got, however, was an archive of JPEGS. So the full question of the OP remains unsolved.

I suggest to give Calibre a try. It's in the repo (= doesn't require 3rd party resources) and a good tool anyway :)

Comment: In the Linuxaria page you link, the only programme listed as capable of reading GIF images is [Comical](http://comical.sourceforge.net/index.php?id=4).

Comment: @LuísdeSousa My interpretation was that Comical can (also) display separate GIF and other image files, while the others might be able to read them (only) when they are part of an archive. Does it make sense? Honestly, I don't know. I might be completely wrong :)